# How do you indicate plural with abbreviations in lowercase?

Tags: plural-forms, abbreviations

If I want to make a lowercase abbreviation plural, how do I do it? I've found loads and loads of information about how to pluralise acronyms, written in uppercase, but nothing about lowercase abbreviations. It seems to me that the normal process of simply adding an *s* doesn't really work in this case?

Examples:

1. You should be more specific – don't use so many *etc*[PLURAL]
2. You need the documents with the following RefNo[PLURAL]
3. There are so many *sic*[PLURAL] in this quote it's ridiculous

(I realise that example 2 would be easily solved by simply writing *reference numbers* instead, but please humour me – if, for some reason, I have to use the abbreviation, then how would I pluralise it?)

Comment: _Nos_ for _numbers_ is a well-established usage.

Comment: The short answer is ***don't do it**!* There's no reason why English should have "evolved" a "correct" written form for such pathological contexts, and it's easy to rephrase and avoid the problem. For example, *You should be more specific – **don't use "etc." so often.*** As @kate points out, pluralising ***s*** appended to abbreviations like ***No, RefNo*** are well-established conventions that doesn't tax the reader unduly (though ***No's, RefNo's*** aren't uncommon). but ***etcs*** and ***sics*** don't really cut it, being references to things which are very rarely pluralised anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I totally see your point, but surely there must still be a rule for it? Or is the rule just that it can't (and shouldn't) be done?? I mean, even though it's usually possible to rephrase, it seems odd that there shouldn't be a rule for those cases where it just can't be avoided (not that I can think of such an example now, but still)?

Comment: Pluralised ***nos*** is probably the most common abbreviation relevant to this situation, but note that when "No" means "a NO vote", as in ***The noes have it** = The majority voted "**No**"*, it's not *that* uncommon to see it transcribed as ***nos*** or ***no's***. When it's an abbreviation, as in *[multiple] [reference **nos***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22reference+nos%22), Google Books has page after page of hits for [*reference **no's***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22reference+no%27s%22) as well. Either make your own choice, or follow ***your*** style guide.

Comment: You could spell out _etceteras_, I suppose.